# WooCommerce Move Upsells into Tabs and display with short description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a dev site here that displays upsales below the tabs:

http://demo.bergdahl.com/product/6-oz-catridge/

I want to change it up a little. I would like the upsells to display within the actual tabs. There will be three tabs: Description, Quantity Pricing, and Other Products.

There are three things I am trying to accomplish and am unsure how to do.

1. Remove the "We might also suggest" text and images from upsells below the tab area.
2. We want the same upsells to appear with just the thumbnail and title (no pricing) under the Description and Quantity Pricing tabs.
3. We want the Other Products tab to show similar Upsell information but with the Thumbnail Image on the left and the Title and *Product Short Description* on the right.

Basically I am looking for the location of the current upsell code to remove it from where it is and the ability to edit that code to place it elsewhere. removing the price and adding the short description where necessary. I can lay it out in code when I have the code needed.

Codes needed are calls for:

**Upsell Product Image 

Upsell Product Title**
**Upsell Product Short Description**

Also if you know it I need the code to display the **Product Variation Description** to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php you'll see that the action `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` pulls in `woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs`and `woocommerce_upsell_display`.

Taking the `woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs` for example, a quick search for this throughout the WooCommerce files using my text editor finds the function in includes/wc-template-functions.php.  Here shows that the function simply includes the template `single-product/tabs/tabs.php`.

If you keep following the path(it can get quite long at times) you will find the tabs are located in a function called woocommerce_default_product tabs and hook into woocommerce_product_tabs.  This is how I debug and find things in WooCommerce.

The best way to then add a tab would be to add the following code to your functions.php, rather than editing the default_tabs in the file directly or copying it to your theme to override.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {

// Adds the new tab

$tabs['test_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'New Product Tab', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 50,
    'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
);

return $tabs;

}
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {

// The new tab content

echo '<h2>New Product Tab</h2>';
echo '<p>Here\'s your new product tab.</p>';

}
```

You have quite a few different customisations to make here but following this general guide, with a little searching, you should be able to find all the hooks and functions and make the changes.

Comment: Thank you, I have actually already added the tabs I need and you can see them on the link I supplied above. I am looking for code to display the following where I want to on the site: Upsell Product Image, Upsell Product Title, Upsell Product Short Description, Product Variation Description,

Comment: I am also looking for how to remove the upsell info that appears below the tabs.